# Winforms maximized windowstate exceeds monitor size for 64bit application

Tags: winforms, 64-bit

I'm migrating a Windows Forms application from 32bit to 64bit.  One issue noticed is that the Form in maximized state in x64 overflows the monitor.
Monitor resolution in both cases is 1920 x 1080
Size when setting Maximized state in both cases is 1936 x 1096
However in 32bit it fits the screen perfectly but in 64bit the outer edge exceeds the screen.
Setting the border style to none does fit it better, but it leaves out the border margin around the app and hides the task bar which i dont want:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Can anyone suggest any pointers please?

Comment: You didn't mention how do you set the `MaximumSize` property of your borderless Form to fit the working area of a screen. Just in case, override the Form's `OnHandleCreated` method, add this line: `this.MaximumSize = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size;`, and try. Also, is your app DpiAware? It has to be.

Comment: Are you comparing different Systems? In Windows 10, a Window has an invisible border (7 + 1 pixels all around). It doesn't matter whether the app is 32bit or 64bit. Also, when a Window is maximized in a `1920 x 1080` Screen, clearly its Size is not `1936 x 1096` with a standard border. The `Width` will be `1936` (`1920 + (7 + 1) * 2`). But, as mentioned, those borders are invisible. The System knows it. -- You didn't say what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The size of a Window maximized in the Primary Screen is returned by `SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorMaximizedWindowSize`, from which you can derive the maximized size in other Screens.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but setting this.MaximumSize is very restrictive for our users, they would like to stretch application much beyond.  Any idea what is the underlying root cause that would cause an x64 to overflow the monitor in maximized size? Issue does not occur in x32.